# Pointer to pointer parameter in Swift function

Tags: objective-c, pointers, recursion, swift

How do you do pointers to pointers in Swift? In Objective-C I had a function which I would call recursively so that I could keep track of the number of recursions, but I'm stumped as to how to achieve this in Swift.

```
NSNumber *recursionCount = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:-1];
[self doRecursion:&recursionCount];

- (void)doRecursion:(NSNumber **)recursionCount {
    // I'm sure this is a terrible way to increment, but I have limited Objective-C experience
    // and this worked, so I moved on after failing to find a decent var++ equivalent :-(
    int addThis = (int)i + 1;
    *recursionCount = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[*recursionCount intValue] + addThis];
    [self doRecursion:recursionCount];
}
```

In the process of cutting this sample down for this post, I've ended up creating a never-ending loop, but you get the idea on how I'm remembering the value with each recursion.

Does anybody know how to do this in Swift? Thanks.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usage of pointers in swift is highly discouraged.

To change a variable passed as argument to a function, you have to pass it by reference (similar to passing its pointer) using the `inout` modifier. I've changed the logic of your function to stop after 10 iterations:

```
func doRecursion(inout recursionCount: Int) -> Int {
    if (recursionCount < 10) {
        ++recursionCount
         doRecursion(&recursionCount)
    }

    return recursionCount
}
```

Then you can call using:

```
var counter: Int = -1
let x = doRecursion(&counter) // Prints 10 in playground
```

Suggested reading: [In-Out Parameters](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/Functions.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH10-XID_267)

Comment: Thanks. I must have missed or skimmed the section on inout parameters. I even tried AutoreleasingUnsafeMutablePointer<Int> and UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>, but that led me down a path of sorrow :)